# Tensorflow Error : Cannot assign a device for operation 'Bincount' ... because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

So, I'm getting the following error :

" *Cannot assign a device for operation 'Bincount_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: Bincount_1 = Bincount[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](ToInt32_1, Minimum_1, Const_7)]]* "

And to me, this is very weird. Because I'm trying to run the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

K = 4
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    X = tf.constant(np.array([1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,3,3,3,2,1,2,0]))
    count = tf.bincount(tf.to_int32(X), minlength = 4, maxlength = 4)

sess = tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto( log_device_placement = True ) )
print( sess.run(count) )
```

And what is weird to me is that when I run the a slightly different code, it works :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

K = 4
X = tf.constant(np.array([1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,3,3,3,2,1,2,0]))
count = tf.bincount(tf.to_int32(X), minlength = 4, maxlength = 4)

sess = tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto( log_device_placement = True ) )
print( sess.run(count) )
```

And, if I remove the **tf.bincount** function, it also works.

So my question is, why does **tf.bincount** causes an error when trying to use device placement ?

And I really need this function to work. 
Also, the system I'm running is an 8 K-40 GPUs with python3, tensorflow 1.2 .

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, currently, there is no support for tf.bincount(...) in gpu.

There has been a request in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11554